# RSpec expect account returns nil compared using ==

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I am trying to create a controller spec for my accounts controller. I am using devise for my authentication and a user has to sign in before being able to access any content on the site.

Here is the spec I have written:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe AccountsController do
  before (:each) do
    user = FactoryBot.create(:user, role: 'admin')
  end

  describe 'GET index' do
    it 'assigns @accounts' do
      account = FactoryBot.create(:account)
      get :index
      expect(assigns(:accounts)).to eq([account])
    end
  end
end
```

I am also using pundit for auth so this does mean the user has to have the role of `admin` in order to access the page which is being done in the before statement above the index test.

This is the error I am getting:

```
Failure/Error: expect(assigns(:accounts)).to eq([account])

expected: [#<Account id: 140, name: "cool account", created_at: "2018-04-13 02:53:38", updated_at: "2018-04-13 ... 02:53:38", logo_file_name: nil, logo_content_type: nil, logo_file_size: nil, logo_updated_at: nil>]
got: nil
```

The index action in my `accounts` controller is very simple.

```
def index
  @accounts = Account.all
  authorize @accounts
end
```

Why would this be returning `nil` if I am clearly creating the account in the `index` action? I am just getting started with testing so forgive me if this is blatantly obvious. After looking at numerous SO posts about this and trying their solutions I came up with no fix.

Here are my factories as well.

**Account factory**

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :account do
    name 'cool account'
  end
end
```

**User factory**

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :user do
    first_name { Faker::Name.first_name }
    last_name  { Faker::Name.last_name }
    email      { Faker::Internet.email }
    password   "password"
  end
end
```

Comment: What happens when you add a puts just after `@account = Account.all` of `puts @accounts.inspect` ? Do you have any `before_action`s in your `accounts_controller`?

Comment: You created the user in the spec but didn't sign in him - that's why spec is failed, I think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you have is that you are creating a user in the `before(:each)` but you're not signing him in. So the Controller's action is never executed because it doesn't go through the Devise authentication.

```
before (:each) do
  user = FactoryBot.create(:user, role: 'admin')
end
```

What you need to do is, first add the Devise helpers to your `spec/rails_helper.rb`:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include Devise::Test::ControllerHelpers, type: :controller
end
```

Note that I added that inside the `RSpec` block.

After that you can use the `sign_in` helper, so you should sign your user in like this in your test:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe AccountsController do
  before (:each) do
    sign_in FactoryBot.create(:user, role: 'admin')
  end

  describe 'GET index' do
    it 'assigns @accounts' do
      account = FactoryBot.create(:account)
      get :index
      expect(assigns(:accounts)).to eq([account])
    end
  end
end
```

And it should work.

You can find more information here > https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Test-controllers-with-Rails-3-and-4-%28and-RSpec%29